# Invalid constant value in const constructor of Flutter/Dart class

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, constants

I want to create a bunch of `const` colored boxes. The following code works:

```
class MyBox extends SizedBox {
  const MyBox(Color color, {Key? key}) // [*1] color parameter
  : super(key: key,
    width:  20,
    height: 40,
    child: const DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.multiply,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        color: Colors.green,         // [*2] all boxes are green
        // color: color,             // [*3] this is what I want
      ),
    ),
  );
}
    [...]
    static const mbRed    = MyBox(Colors.red);
    static const mbYellow = MyBox(Colors.yellow);
    static const mbBlue   = MyBox(Colors.blue);
```

But notice that the `color` parameter at line `[*1]` is not actually used. If I replace line `[*2]` with line `[*3]`, I am told this is an `Invalid constant value`. (Note that the `Color` class are immutable 32-bit values.)

Somehow there must be a way to pass a color parameter to a `const constructor`. What am I doing wrong?

And if this is the wrong way to go about it, what *is* a succinct means of creating a bunch of boxes, identical except for color? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  When you declare `MyBox`'s constructor as `const`, that means that the constructor *can* be used to create a compile-time constant, not that it *must* be.  Meanwhile, when that constructor itself invokes `const DecoratedBox`, you're stating that `DecoratedBox` is guaranteed to be a compile-time constant, but you cannot guarantee that.  For example, `MyBox` could have been constructed with a `Color` determined at runtime.

Unfortunately Dart has no way to recursively say "try to invoke this constructor as `const` *if possible*".  You will have to declare the `MyBox` constructor as a non-`const` constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I think I see. My objective was to make these small UX elements `const` to avoid rebuilds when their parents call `SetState()`... it seems like a weakness in the system that I can verbosely write each one out individually, but have no way to create an abstraction. Thanks again.